# users in Local Admin on cloud machine(virtual Machine) as well as in physical machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cloud, virtual, local

I am adding users in Local Admin under some domain in Virtual Machine(Cloud Machine) as well as in Physical machine. But adding users in Virtual machine code takes 1 min more time as compare to physical machine. I am using the same code.

Comment: Might be good to show the code also

Comment: Hi Sami Kuhmonen Please refer this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843469/adding-local-user-to-local-admin-group